# Scrapy - scrape of all of the item instead of 1 item

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape all of the items but only 1 item is scrape.
My code is working fine before but when I transfer it to other project which is same code this happens I don't know why

I need to get all of the items according to the page size in start_url

here's my working code

```
class HmSalesitemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'HM_salesitem'
    allowed_domains = ['www2.hm.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view- 
all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page- 
size=3002']

def parse(self, response):  
    for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
        url = "https://www2.hm.com/" + product_item.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first() 
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_subpage)

def parse_subpage(self, response):
    item = {
    'title': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//h1[contains(@class, 'primary') and contains(@class, 'product-item-headline')]/text())").extract_first(),
    'sale-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='price-value']/text())").extract_first(), 
    'regular-price': response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "whitePrice")]/text()').re_first("'whitePrice'\s?:\s?'([^']+)'"),
    'photo-url': response.css('div.product-detail-main-image-container img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
    'description': response.css('p.pdp-description-text::text').extract_first()

    }   
    yield item
```

Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have problem with indents. Move yielding request to `for` loop:

```
def parse(self, response):  
    for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
        url = "https://www2.hm.com/" + product_item.css('a::attr(href)').get() 
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```

Or this is a bit cleared version:

```
def parse(self, response):  
    for link in response.css('li.product-item a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield response.follow(link, self.parse_subpage)
```

Comment: Oh F! I've just overlooked my code and forget about indention, now it works fine thanks @vezunchik

Comment: It will be great, if you will accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Vezunchik that's a bonus help